# Create new method

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I'm working with HP UFT. This tool use VBScript to automatics test.
Is it possible to create new method in function library. 
I mean something like this.

```
Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebEdit("login").MyMethod()
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the **Design** menu, and select **Function Definition Generator...**
You'll get the following UI
[image: function generator]

Basically this is a helper for [`RegisterUserFunc`](http://www.automationrepository.com/2011/12/understanding-registeruserfunc-syntax-with-example/).

By selecting the **Register to a test object** check-box (and which type of test object) the function you add will be available as a regular test object function.

Note that you can override an existing function, for example you can change `Set` to see if the value is `"~today~"` add today's date.

Answer (score 1):

Adding User Defined Functions is actually pretty easy: define the function, decide on the object type you wish to add the function to, and use RegisterUserFunc to put it all together:

```
Function BrokenImage(ImageObject)
BrokenImage = True
ImageObject.WaitProperty "visible", True, 1000
ImageLoaded = False
StartTime = Now()
Do
    If ImageObject.Object.naturalHeight > 0 And ImageObject.Object.naturalHeight > 0 Then
        BrokenImage = False
        Exit Do 
    End If
    If DateDiff("s", StartTime, Now()) > 10 Then Exit Do
Loop While ImageLoaded = False
End Function 

RegisterUserFunc "Image", "BrokenImage", "BrokenImage"
```

Once you've got the function defined, you call it as you would any other object method:

```
If Browser().Page().Image().ImageBroken() = true Then Print "Broken Image"
```

You can also add additional parameters which will then be passed to the new method.